# Excel's INDEX MATCH issues with text great than 254 characters in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

My `Index` and `Match` functions work file for all rows (over a hundred) except three rows where text is great than 255 characters where it returns #Value.

I created an example to understand the problem where playing with numbers, it seems to work when text cell is under 254 characters but returns `#####` for larger length cell values. The `MATCH` part does return correct results as can be seen in attached image but `Index` part returns `####`.

Full fomula

```
=INDEX(H9:H21,MATCH(K7,F9:F21,0))
```

Only Match formula (that does always work)

```
=MATCH(K7,F9:F21,0)
```

[image]

If I shorten the text to less than 254 characters, it always works.

How do I get INDEX MATCH to work with longer texts?

Comment: Which version of Excel?

Comment: With a quick googling, MATCH has a 255 character limit. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72580007/bypass-255-character-limit-of-index-match-function-with-vba) from July -22 in Stack Overflow, _If you have the latest version of Excel, you can use the XMATCH function. It doesn't have the 255 character limit._

Comment: Also, just in case, check the format of the cell with long text. Perhaps your problem is related to the limitation of the Index() function, or maybe you are faced with [**this situation**](https://forum.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/43817-index-function-limit-on-string-length/&postID=439192#post439192).

Comment: Using Excel365, and thanks for the leads.

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I get INDEX MATCH to work with longer texts?

> To match text longer than 255 characters with the `MATCH` function,
> you can use the `LEFT`, `MID`, and `EXACT` functions to parse and
> compare text, as explained below. In the example shown, the formula in
> G5 is:
>
> ```
> =MATCH(1,EXACT(LEFT(E5,255),LEFT(data,255))*EXACT(MID(E5,256,255),MID(data,256,255)),0)
> ```
>
> where data is the named range `B5:B15`.[image]

Source: [Match long text - Excel formula | Exceljet](https://exceljet.net/formulas/match-long-text)

Alternatively, as [Peregrino69](https://superuser.com/users/330527/peregrino69) points out in a comment on the question, you can use `XMATCH` as it does not have the 255 character limit. See [excel - Bypass 255 character limit of Index MATCH Function with VBA - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72580007/bypass-255-character-limit-of-index-match-function-with-vba) for more information.